# Compare two ArrayList on Java with operatiors "||" or "&&"

Tags: java, arraylist, linked-list

I got two ArrayList with Strings inside, so I want to compare those Strings with logical comparators || or && ("or" or "and") comparators and put result in a third ArrayList

Assuming

First Array contains:
     "Hi", "Sun", "Lamp", "pencil"
Second Array contains
      "Sun", "chicken", "Hi"

So the result in third is suppose contains 
       "Sun", "Hi"

Comment: Have you read a tutorial on Java operators? What do the `||` and `&&` operators apply to?

Comment: Can you include some code you tried?

Comment: use `equals()` instead of logical operators

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int i=0;i< firstlist.size();i++) {
   if(firstlist.get(i)!=null && secondlist.get(i)!=null) {
       if(firstlist.get(i).equals(secondlist.get(i))) {
          thirdlist.add(firstlist.get(i));
       }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The && and || operators are logical operators, i.e. they take 2 boolean expressions and return either true or false. The comparison of Strings is done using the equals() method from the String class. E.g. "hi".equals("world") returns false.

It looks like what you need to do is to iterate through the first arrayList and check if elements in it are contained in the second arrayList using the equals() method.